# Can the auxiliary ～やがる be used with passive voice?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

I thought I heard someone use it in this way recently, but it just a conversation I overheard so I cannot be sure exactly. A standard use might be:
「あいつが邪魔しやがった。」

But can it ever be combined with a passive voice so the speaker can convey additional inconvenience? For example, something like this:
「あいつに邪魔されやがった。」This might be ungrammatical or not, I don't know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

「やがる」 used in conjunction with verbs in passive voice forms is totally possible and grammtical.  It is so even though one must know that the said usage is far less common than with verbs in active voice forms.

One thing I must mention, however, is the fact that when the above-mentioned usage of 「やがる」 takes place, the subject of the sentence would be a third person ***far more often*** than it is the speaker himself.  Let us take your sentence as an example:

> 「あいつに邪魔{じゃま}されやがった。」

If given this sentence with absolutely no context, nearly 100% of native speakers would think that the subject of the sentence would be an unmentioned third person.

> "(Someone) was f***in' bothered by that dude."

Though you did not say, I had an impression that you were thinking that the person being bothered was the speaker himself.  That is not impossible at all but it would be rare.  That would be a case of ***self-degradation*** or just plain ***vulgarity***.

> "I was f***in' bothered by that dude."

To clarify my point regarding the subject being more often a third person than the speaker, I meant to say you would hear/see sentences like these:

> 「初回{しょかい}にホームラン3本{ぼん}も打{う}たれやがって！」 = "(The pitcher) allowed 3 damn homeruns in the first inning!"

The baseball club manager might say that about his starting pitcher.  The contempt is expressed toward the pitcher, not the speaker himself.  The subject 「ピッチャー」 is unmentioned here, which should be nothing new to you.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes, I was intending the subject of the sentence to be the speaker, not a 3rd party. If I wanted to make sure it was understood in this way, how could I express the sentence in Japanese and still use the passive?　俺はあいつに邪魔されやがった。 ?　Sounds strange to me

Comment: That in deed sounds a bit strange, but not totally impossible.  That sounds as if the speaker was more pissed at himself than at the other guy.   Someone with severe self-hatred might say that.  It would not be said commonly at all, but I just could not say it is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 8):

あいつに邪魔されやがった isn't ungrammatical, but it would be unnatural in the context you're probably thinking of, because やがる indicates negative feeling towards the subject of the verb it's attached to. So in this case the speaker would be angry not at the person who did the obstructing, but the person who was obstructed.

So the sentence doesn't really work at all if we assume a first-person subject, because that would mean the speaker is getting angry at *himself*. If I hear あいつに邪魔されやがった, I imagine an exchange like:

> で、ブツは持ってるのか？例の邪魔するやろうにはちゃんと気をつけたんだろうな？
>   "So, have you got the goods? I hope you made sure not to let you-know-who get in the way again."
>
> いや…田中のやつ、今回は絶対持ってくるって言ってたのに、結局あいつに邪魔されやがった。
>   "No... Tanaka said he'd bring it for sure this time, but in the end he went and let that guy get in his way."
>
> またかよ！本当に使えねぇな、田中のやつ！
>   "Not again! You can't trust that Tanaka with anything!"

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Your example is pretty funny, what is it from?

Comment: I just came up with it off the top of my head, haha.